# How to serve node.js service for worldwide customers and fast?

Tags: node.js, firebase, cloud, hosting

I have a local VPS that hosting and providing my Node.js REST API in my country.
However soon I will need to open it for different countries.
That means that clients from remote will ask for my services.
Since they are far it will be probably slow connection.
How can I avoid this? Maybe I need more servers located in their countries too, but still, how the data could be shared over one DB?

I do not looking for a full tutorial for how to do that (could be nice to have) but I am looking for get info about the methodology of this.

What do you recommend to do, keep buying servers in remote countries, sharing their data between them someway, or maybe choose to use some cloud service like Firebase? How cloud services work in first place?

Answer (score 0):

Without going into too much detail for each item, here are some keypoints in which I think you should focus your on learning to solve your problem.

- For data storage - look into firestore (not the json database) as firestore is globally scaleable.
- For your REST endpoints I would use google cloud functions, but without knowing the nature of your application its hard to say if its suitable. The key to being able to reach global scale is having cacheable endpoints. Then you are leveraging google's global CDN which is much faster than hitting the origin server. *Note: The firebase cloud functions infrastructure WILL face cold start issues which may/may not be a problem for you.*
- Cache invalidation is a little lacking so you can leverage longer max-age cache settings but use either cache busing and/or the header stale-while-revalidate to help with this.

There is some great info here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbV-293m1dQ that covers some of what I have mentioned in more detail.